# Weird COM issue with classic ASP

Tags: asp-classic, com

I have a COM component that I would like to use from Classic ASP. It is registered correctly using both the 64 and 32 bit version of `regasm`, using the `/codebase` switch.

All assemblies are signed with a strong name (although the key is not protected with a password). When I register the types, I get a confirmation that they were registered successfully.

If I make a VBScript file that attempts to create the COM component, it succeeds without issues when I run it with both the 64 and the 32 bit version of `cscript.exe`.

However, when I try to do a `Server.CreateObject` on the exact same COM component, I get the following error:

> Server object error 'ASP 0177 : 80070002'
>
> Server.CreateObject Failed
>
> somefile.asp, line 2
>
> 80070002

The line provided by the excepton just contains the `Server.CreateObject` statement.

The assembly is `AnyCPU`, and the type I am trying to expose has a `[ComVisible(true)]` attribute set on it. The rest of the assembly is not COM visible.

Any clue on what I am experiencing here? I tried giving full permission to `Everyone` for the DLL files because I originally thought it was an IIS issue. However, that simply doesn't seem to be the case.

*I have Googled this for many hours and seen countless similar questions, but this is not related, since none of the proposed solutions work.*

Comment: in ancient time i did registration by using c:\windows\syswow64\regsvr32.exe for 32bit COM components on x64 OS and by using c:\windows\system32\regsvr32.exe for 64bit COM components on x64 OS

Comment: asp is 32bit. did you allow to run 32bit app's in IIS for your app pool?

Comment: 80070002 is ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND. Use Process Monitor to see what is missing.

Comment: @ShengJiang蒋晟 Process monitor doesn't seem to show anything of relevance. @Zam yes, it doesn't make a difference. Also, note that this is a .NET component so `regsvr32` won't work, `regasm` must be used instead.

Comment: Might help if you explain what the COM component does it terms of initialisation, does it depend on certain files or folder structure for example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it, but as I suspected, it wasn't the same cause as seen in other questions.

Apparently if you try to register a DLL from a network share, it will provide those symptoms, although the message is "Types registered successfully".

Very scary.

When moving all my DLLs to a local folder on the machine, they registered and ran successfully without issues.

Comment: A very important point you failed to mention in the question.

Comment: I mentioned everything I thought was relevant. Why would I think that accessing from a network share would be relevant if it doesn't report an error?

Comment: Why would you be accessing a COM DLL from a network share in the first place on a Web Server? The `80070002` error gives away the fact it's file related be it missing file or file permission same ball park.

Comment: Just something to think about in future when asking a question, the more information you can provide the better the answers will be. At least you're sorted now.

Comment: "Why would I think..." -- [Service Running as System Account Fails Accessing Network](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/124184)

Answer (score 2):

If it works correctly with cscript.exe and failed in ASP, almost all the time that is due to the security context or file/register permission issue. ASP runs under the IIS user realm, and you will need to ensure that user ID has access to all the resources (including temp file/folder) needed for your COM object.